# Regex: Match Empty \s inside [' ']

Tags: regex

Hello I'm trying to match the  white space character(`\s`) to could be any of this [\r\n\t\f ] values  only inside the text  the [' ']

For example

```
$lang['some random text'] = 'some random text';
$lang['other random text'] = 'other random text';
```

I'm looking to replace white space for _. For example the above example will end in the following format.

```
$lang['some_random_text'] = 'some random text';
$lang['other_random_text'] = 'other random text';
```

Language: Plain regex

Could someone explain what will be the right approach ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your regex matches `['<one or more spaces>']`, what exactly doesn't work? Please note that you don't have to escape the last `'`.

Comment: I'm looking to match the empty|spaces values inside the text ['one or more  space(s)']. so it can be replaced by some value eg: ['one_or_more_space(s)']

Comment: yes something like this   ['one or more space(s)']   to be transformed to for example ['one_or_more_space(s)']

Comment: Can you show a complete line of code, on how you are currently using `\['\w+\']`? thanks

Comment: Wouldn't replacing all blank spaces by underline solve it?

Comment: @JorgeCampos  I want to target only spaces|blank| inside the text in brackets [] excluding other text.

Comment: inside a string there is no "blank" (unless it is an encoded char) what are you calling a blank? can you show a sample ?

Comment: I'm looking to match the \s that is  any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

Comment: Ok, and why don't you use this regex `\['[\r\n\t\f]+'\]`

Comment: What is the programming language? Where are you going to perform the search and replace? The right approach: get the strings inside `[]` and replace spaces inside the callback method. See [the C# demo](http://ideone.com/k4Pn3V).

Comment: Programming language? Please mention clearly and update your question.

Comment: Suggest two steps: 1)  match what is inside []; 2) search one or more spaces(s) with the match in 1).

Comment: There is no *plain regex*. Regex has lots of flavors. What will work in PHP might not work in .NET.

Comment: Ok thanks,  a regex expression that runs here https://regex101.com/ or webstorm https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html